# Posting data with ajax issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post

I am trying to pass object to HttpPost method with ajax.

This is my ajax method:

```
function addItem(invoiceID) {
var newItemVM = {
    Description : $('#item-description').val(),
    Quantity : $('#item-quantity').val(),
    ItemTaxFreePrice : $('#item-tax-free-price').val()
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'AddItem',
    data: JSON.stringify({ newItemVM: newItemVM }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        $('#new-item').text(result.Quantity + 'Hello');
    }
});
```

}

This is the HttpPost method in C#

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddItem(NewItemVM newItemVM)
    {
        return Json(newItemVM);
    }
```

This is NewItemVM class:

```
public class NewItemVM
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public double ItemTaxFreePrice { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that the parameters in newItemVM object are allways null.

Can somebody tell me what am I missing out? Tnq!

Comment: Have you tried to hard-create simple newItemVM object? For example `{ Description: 'desc', Quantity: 0, ItemTaxFreePrice:0 }`

Comment: Note that all that is necessary is `data: newItemVM,` and remove the `contentType` option

Comment: C# code is in Webapi or in MVC?

Comment: And strinfy the object passing to ajax call and console it

Comment: C# code is in MVC

Comment: @TomasChabada I have tried that and I still can't get the data in C#

Comment: When I remove content type than i can sand data if I hard code it

Comment: The result of JSON.stringify is this: {"Description":"dssdf","Quantity":"0","ItemTaxFreePrice":"0"}

Answer (score 0):

hi you don't need to specify the name of the your model in json object call should be like below

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'AddItem',
    data:  newItemVM ,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        $('#new-item').text(result.Quantity + 'Hello');
    }
});
```